# Increasing function $g(x)$

Tags: calculus

> If $g$ is increasing and $g(x)\neq 0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\frac{1}{g}$ is decreasing.

I have no idea.
I am new to function analysis, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you know what is the meaning of "increasing" and "decreasing" for a function?

Comment: Your statement is not true as given. Do you have additional information, such as that $g$ is continuous, or is always positive, or something else?

Comment: @uniquesolution yes

Comment: @RoryDaulton no, that is all given

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you solve the question you deleted about the number of permutations of the letters of the word PHONOLOGY in which no two Os are consecutive?

Answer (score 4):

Your statement "If $g$ is increasing and $g(x)\neq 0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\frac{1}{g}$ is decreasing" is not true as given. Here is a counterexample:

$$g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  x-1, & x \lt 0 \\
  x+1, & x \ge 0
\end{cases}$$

Then $g$ is an increasing function, but

$$g(-1) = -\frac 12 < \frac 12 = g(1)$$

so $\dfrac 1g$ is not a decreasing function. Here are the graphs of $g$ and $\dfrac 1g$.

[image]

[image]

Note that $\dfrac 1g$ is a *locally decreasing* function at any point other than zero, meaning that at any value of $x$ (other than zero) there is an open interval around $x$ where $\dfrac 1g$ is decreasing, but that is not your statement. Note also that if you know that $g$ is continuous on the real numbers then $g$ cannot "skip over" zero as my example does and your statement is then true.